# Using an associated models columns for virtualFields?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a **User** model and an **Order** model. User *hasMany* Order.

The orders table has a user_id column as well as a total column.

I would like to have a `virtulField` on the User model that is the count of how many orders are associate with that user.

I would also like to have a virtualField on the User that is the sum of all the totals.

The only way I have been able to get this to work is like so:

```
public $virtualFields = array(
    'total_orders' => '(SELECT COUNT(orders.user_id) FROM orders WHERE orders.user_id = User.id AND orders.status != "void" GROUP BY orders.user_id)',
    'total_sales' => '(SELECT SUM(orders.total) FROM orders WHERE orders.user_id = User.id AND orders.status != "void" GROUP BY orders.user_id)',
);
```

I am not sure if this is the best solution though, is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

for total order: use counterCache with counterScope: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1033/counterCache-Cache-your-count

you still need virtualField for total sales though.